# java.lang.NullPointerException on onResume()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have Fragment A and Fragment B, on fragment A i have an input searchbox and when I open the fragment it shows the softkeyboard which is intended. When switching fragments sometimes a NullPointerException occurs. I cannot reproduce the error but the log file says that the error occurs on the `onResume()` function. Below is the code i used on my onResume(), what can be the reason i get `java.lang.NullPointerException`?

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    if (getActivity().getWindow().getCurrentFocus() == searchbox) {
        searchbox.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm != null) {
                    imm.showSoftInput(searchbox, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            }
        }, 300);
    }
}
```

Edit:
Here is logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.myapp.fragments.MyMain$7.run (MyMain.java:258)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:815)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5811)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:907)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:768)
```

Comment: `getActivity` inside the run method may execute while the fragment is not attached to any activity.... and so null

Answer (score 2):

Inside the run method you have:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

`getActivity()` may be `null` if the fragment is not attached to the Activity after `300` milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Null pointer exception means you are trying to work with a variable that has not been initialized yet. So in your onResume method, check all the variables. Make sure they survive the activity distruction. Because many variables don't resume in the onResume. 
You will need to figure out which variable is giving null pointer exception and then initialize that variable in the onResume method.

You can use try catch method on each code line in your onResume method to fugure out which of the codeline is giving error. in catch method you can print out the error to console as follows

```
try{
//1st code line
}catch{ System.out.println("1st line gives the error")
}
```

Comment: it is not a good idea to use try/catch to handle NPE. instead, try to debug your method to figure out at which line you are using not initialized object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agreewith magnetar. That should solve your issue.

```
try{
            //code line 1
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i(TAG, "method: "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

try this on each line
Another way you can go about it is by debugging your project and adding breakpoints in onResume method. That could be more helpful.